# How to nicely evaluate nested StateT and ErrorT monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have two type declarations for control structures at different levels in a program. The bottom one is the `Agent`, a `StateT` with `IO` capabilities. The second one is another `StateT` with `Agent` capabilities, and the third one (`Plan`) is an `ErrorT`.

```
type Agent = StateT AgentState IO
type Plan = ErrorT PlanError (StateT PlanState Agent)
```

What is the best way to evaluate a `Plan`? I wrote the following code, but it is not very handful because there are loads of nested `runStateT` and `runErrorT` calls.

```
foo :: Plan ()
defaultAgentState :: AgentState
runStateT (runStateT (runErrorT foo) (PlanState 0)) defaultAgentState
```

Is there something simpler/nicer?

Comment: You can define a `runPlan` function, so you'd need to stack only once, not every time you call it.

Comment: But `runPlan` would be defined just like my last expression that puts together `runStateT` and `runErrorT`, right? There's no shortcut in general, If I have a stack of monad transformers in order to run them I have to stack the right amount of `runXyzT`.
I'm sorry for the probably dumb question, but I'm quite new to MTL, I find it still a little bit difficult.

Comment: Right. At some place each of the `runXyzT` has to be called, there's no way around that. But it's enough to do it in one place, so if you execute many `Plan`s, you needn't explicitly repeat the stack each time. The question is definitely not dumb, by the way.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! If you paste these few comment lines of yours into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You might also want to write wrappers around the `State` functions, `get`, `put`, `modify`, `gets`, etc... to hide the `lift`, and to make it clear when you are operating on the `AgentState` vs the `PlanState`.

Comment: I already did it, thank you @pat :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a monad transformer stack, each of the `runXyzT` functions of the individual transformers has to be called at some point, there is unfortunately no shortcut.

However, if you use a particular stack more than once, it is worthwhile to define a special `runMyStack` function, so that the clutter of the stacked `runXyzT` appears only at one point.